# PayPal SetExpressCheckout vs. payment buttons

Tags: paypal

What is the benefit of calling PayPal API SetExpressCheckout method to get a payment link and forwarding a customer there instead of using payment buttons?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The PayPal buttons can be modified by the visitor's browser client. It is just basic HTML. All of the variables to place the order can be manipulated by the customer. For instance, it takes 3 seconds to change the order total from $900 to $1.

Using the API, you tell PayPal to create an incomplete transaction for a certain amount, with certain information, that can then be referenced/completed later and there is no way (short of expert hacking) to change the order. Instead of trusting the visitor's browser, PayPal trusts your server.